# Ef composite key fluent api with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have

```
public class FriendshipConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Friendship>
{
    public FriendshipConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(k => new { k.FromUserId, k.ToUserId })
            .HasRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(m=> m.Friendships)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.FromUserId, e.ToUserId })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

with the following tables

```
public class Friendship
{
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string FromUserId { get; set; }
    public string ToUserId { get; set; }
    public FriendshipStatus FriendshipStatusId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ResponseDateTimeTime { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
}
```

I want by the end having (FromUserId, ToUserId) Primary composite Keys and also Foreign keys to ApplicationUser.

I am having the following error

> Friendship_ApplicationUser_Target_Friendship_ApplicationUser_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Comment: The composite PK configuration (`HasKey`) is ok. The FK/relationships are not. Start with the fact that you have 2 relationships, hence you need 2 `ApplicationUser` reference navigation properties and 2 `ICollection<Friendship>` collection navigation properties, both mapped to a *single* FK property - one for `FromUserId` and one for `ToUserId`.

Comment: thank you for the answer